# How do I interactively pass arguments to cURL from the shell?

Tags: shell, curl, arguments, interactive, hardcode

I want to create an alias to get a file using cURL which prompts for the:

- URL
- output path
- username and password of a proxy

How would I be able to do this interactively rather than hardcoding everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works as expected:

```
alias proxyget='read userid?"Userid: "; read passwd?"Password: "; read url?"URL: "; read local?"Local: "; curl -x 1.2.3.4:8080 -U $userid:$passwd  $url -o $local;'
```

**References**

- [Using cURL to automate HTTP jobs](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html)
- [curl - Manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)
- [read Man Page - Bash - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/read.html)